# Can't get Zend to work with PHP on Windows 7

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader, spl-autoloader

I'm not able to get Zend to work properly on Windows 7 using IIS 7.5.

I have PHP set up and MySQL set up.  This is working.

I work on various websites in various languages (ColdFusion, simply HTML, JSP, etc).  These websites are all located in subfolders of the folder E:/working on my system.  IIS is then configured to point to the appropriate subu folder for each website.  For example if I have the folder E:/working/mysite I would have IIS configured so that http://127.0.0.1/mysite would be associated with that directory and the main page would be displayed (index.cfm, index.html or whatever it is).

So for this project it is PHP.  I have a directory of E:/working/myphpsite.  This is working and http://127.0.0.1/myphpsite displays the index.php file located in that directory.

The problem is that if I put Zend related code into the index.php file I get this message:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Form\Form' not found in E:\working\myphpsite\index.php on line 8

The index.php file starts this way:

```
session_start();

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class UploadForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);
       $this->addElements();
}

?>
```

My PHP directory is E:/PHP.  In that directory I have placed the zend files in E:\PHP\includes\ZendFramework\Library\Zend.  I have also updated the phi.ini file sections to be as follows:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;E:\PHP\includes\ZendFramework\Library"
```

I assume I must be missing something very obvious, but have spent hours searching the internet and haven't found any solutions to this issue.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: `include_path` means nothing if you don't actually include anything. Your code needs to either require/include the referenced class files, or (better) use an autoloader to do it for you.

Comment: Isn't the "use Zend\Form\Form" line doing the include?  Or is there a 'require/include' line that needs to be in the code at the top?  Sorry for what may be a stupid question - just that the code samples we found didn't have anything but what we posted above.

Comment: No, use just registers a shortcut so you don't have to specify the full class name. You still need to include/require the source files or (preferably) use an autoloader.

Comment: Also if you have to specify included files on a individual basis (either through a require/include or the autoloader) what is the point of the include_path option of the php.ini?  What does that actually include?  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what 'use' does - that makes sense.

Comment: The include_path specifies what directories to search through if an include statement does not have a full path name.

Comment: You've tagged your question with Zend autoloader - that's what you need to setup to make it work. The alternative is installing ZF using Composer (which is the most common approach), which means all this is taken care of for you.